# How to convert timestamp (mm:ss.0) to seconds in r

Tags: r

I have the time in one of my excel data columns in this format `00:15.3` , and in the formula bar the value is shown as `12:00:05 am`. I need to convert this to seconds, making the timestamp in the first row of the column as `0` seconds. Reading this excel file in R using `read_excel` makes the first column display the value as `1899-12-31 00:00:16`, but there is no date in the original data. Can someone please help in solving this?

Data:

```
dtf <- structure(list(...1=structure(c(NA, -2209075194.6,
  -2209075185.7), tzone="UTC", class=c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  "C-1"=c("m/s", "23.4", "583.5"), "C-2"=c("m/s", "995.6",
  "33.53"), "C-3"=c("m/s", "26", "44"), "C-4"=c("m/s", "223.76",
  "54.9"), "C-5"=c("m/s", "65.900000000000006", "55.5"),
  "C-6"=c("m/s", "334.3", "0.45"), "C-7"=c(NA, 23.6, 44.6),
  "C- 8 "=c(NA, 243.4, 56.9)), row.names=c(NA, -3L),
  class="data.frame")
```

Comment: Could you share the first few rows of your data.frame, so we know what you're working with? Something like `dput(head(dtf))` – where `dtf` is your data.frame object – should suffice.

Comment: @AkselA Here is the output of ```dput(head(dtf))```:
```structure(list(...1 = structure(c(NA, -2209075194.6, -2209075185.7
), tzone = "UTC", class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")), `C-1` = c("m/s", 
"23.4", "583.5"), `C-2` = c("m/s", "995.6", "33.53"), `C-3` = c("m/s", 
"26", "44"), `C-4` = c("m/s", "223.76", "54.9"), `C-5` = c("m/s", 
"65.900000000000006", "55.5"), `C-6` = c("m/s", "334.3", "0.45"
), `C-7` = c(NA, 23.6, 44.6), `C- 8` = c(NA, 243.4, 56.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))```

Comment: First an most important, without the xlsx file its hard to give exact solutions, but here are some observations. 1) The first line is most likely the header column, but its read as the first row. Solve that first. When I tried it with a dummy xlsx file it worked, even with an empty first row. 2) You can define the column type with `col_types` and its recycled, so `character` should work in your case. You can deal with the conversion of the first variable to e.g. a period with `library(lubridate); ms(c("00:15.3"))` later.

Answer (score 0):

There's some issue with the column headers. They seem to be spanning two rows, or one row is for measurement units. I applied a fix, but there might be a better way to deal with it in the `read_excel()` call. In any case, it won't affect the rest.
Isolating the seconds can be done in a few different ways, but the most straight forward option is probably to convert to `POSIXlt` and extract the `sec` element. Using `strftime()` with `%OS4` specifying seconds with up to four digits precision is also an option. The most efficient method is probably to take advantage of that the underlying structure of `POSIXct` is in decimal seconds ([UNIX time](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). That means we can easily calculate the number of seconds that has elapsed since 1899-12-31 00:00:00, our time zero.

```
dtf <- structure(list(...1=structure(c(NA, -2209075194.6,
  -2209075185.7), tzone="UTC", class=c("POSIXct", "POSIXt")),
  "C-1"=c("m/s", "23.4", "583.5"), "C-2"=c("m/s", "995.6",
  "33.53"), "C-3"=c("m/s", "26", "44"), "C-4"=c("m/s", "223.76",
  "54.9"), "C-5"=c("m/s", "65.900000000000006", "55.5"),
  "C-6"=c("m/s", "334.3", "0.45"), "C-7"=c(NA, 23.6, 44.6),
  "C- 8 "=c(NA, 243.4, 56.9)), row.names=c(NA, -3L),
  class="data.frame")

options(digits.secs=4)

colnames(dtf) <- gsub(" +NA$", "", paste(colnames(dtf), dtf[1,]))
dtf <- dtf[-1,]
dtf[,-1] <- type.convert(dtf[,-1], as.is=TRUE)

(seconds <- as.POSIXlt(dtf[,1])$sec)
# [1]  6.4000001 15.3000002

(seconds <- as.numeric(strftime(dtf[,1], "%OS4")))
# [1]  6.4 15.3

time0 <- as.POSIXct("1899-12-31 00:00:00", tz="UTC") - 1
(seconds <- as.numeric(dtf[,1] - time0))
# [1]  6.4000001 15.3000002

dtf <- cbind(seconds, dtf)
dtf[,-(5:8)]
#      seconds                ...1 C-1 m/s C-2 m/s  C-7  C- 8
# 2  6.4000001 1899-12-31 00:00:06    23.4  995.60 23.6 243.4
# 3 15.3000002 1899-12-31 00:00:15   583.5   33.53 44.6  56.9
```